# php socket server works on localhost but not on live server

Tags: php, apache2, websocket

i am using PHP WebSocket Server 0.2 (http://code.google.com/p/php-websocket-server/) on my development window7 pc using wamp server WAMPServer2.0.

1. I did not installed/activated any Apache modules.
2. Just activated php_sockets extension for php.

My socket server works fine using localhost and LAN IP address on LAN but when i implement same code on with same settings on my live server, it does not works.

On live server

1. after executing "php socket-server.php" there is no error.
2. But when i try to connect to socket server using javascript, it doesn't connects.

My live server is CENTOS 5.8, Apache/2.2.20, PHP/5.2.17.

What i am doing wrong? does Apache needs some extra module?

**-- EDIT --**

Now after contacting support enabled port 9300, but still client cannot connect to server.

But on the server side i have some activity, according to script the client gets disconnect as soon a its connected.

[image]

**-- EDIT --**

Same script is working fine in http://www.turnkeylinux.org/lampstack on vmware.

Comment: Is your live server behind a firewall?

Comment: @Jack, I don't know that. how can i know that and how does it effects?

Comment: ipchains firewall on the live server? is the live server outside your LAN? if so, there could be a number of other firewalls in the way

Comment: I'm assuming you're not running on port 80, so it's typical for web servers to only open port 80 (maybe 22 as well); you can tell by either typing `ipchains -L` on your server or ask ISP

Comment: @BugFinder, Yes live server is out side my LAN.

Comment: @Jack, no i am not using port 80 or 22 but i have tried many others.

Comment: Then Id say your live server is behind a firewall

Comment: @Jack, i have updated the question. Please have a look at it. Thanks.

Comment: @BugFinder, i have updated the question. Please have a look at it. Thanks.

Comment: Is error_reporting set to -1? Maybe you are experiencing a bug specific to the live server and you aren't seeing it.

Comment: @Tiberiu-IonuțStan, no brother is didn't helped.

Comment: How does your iptables look like ??

Comment: @BugFinder - if it were a firewall issue would they be able to connect in the first place? It is showing they are connected then they are being disconnected.

Comment: Have you checked firebug or anything to see if you are getting any javascript errors on the browser side?

Comment: @Pitchinnate, "Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at ws://ipaddress:9300/. this.conn = new WebSocket(url); fancywebsocket.js (line 22)"

Comment: Whats listening on port 9300 on the server?

Comment: @BugFinder, php code which i am using as socket server.

Comment: Is port 9300 open on the firewall? You have at no point shown your code to us, and so, does your code actually work?

Comment: can you show me the content of this file? `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_rmem` (it show the buffer size)

Answer (score 0):

Look the answer is simple

Javascript / Ajax security doesn't support Cross-Domain connections

notice that: if your server is located at http://myserver.com and your script is running on http://myserver.com:9300  then javascript will understand that this is a different domain.

If you want to do so do the following:

1-Create http-proxy using apache where you'll forward  "/live" to http://servers.com:9300
2-Then connect your javascript to /live and the apache proxy will do the job.

If you're stuck in creating proxy then search for "apache proxy pass for openfire" and you'll find a good example on how to.

Please notice that you'll need root access for this, or you can ask your host admin to add this proxy forwarding for you.

Comment: Hi @Shehabox thanks for your response, your point seems to be valid but then how then does it works on localhost? anyway i will try it because i don't have any other option.

Comment: every host is localhost, maybe that explains it?

Comment: @hakre, what do you mean by that in current context?

Comment: Please notice that Different port is understood by Browsers as different host:

localhost:80 and localhost:9080 are different hosts not just port

Answer (score 0):

Try to connect from command line to your websocket server with curl or ncat with the highest verbosity level. If everything fine, i mean, you receive Upgrade header, than probably the problem is in firewall.

You can alsoe use a nmap, which help you a lot to determine is there any opened ports within the range you are trying to open websocket connections.

Also on production environment you should have the error reporting level to E_NONE.

BTW, which kind of live server do you have (VPS/VDS, dedicated, etc.)?